# How can i edit uploaded mp3 files by user

Tags: python, django

**I want my django app to do.**

- User Uploads mp3 file
- user inputs time range
- my app trims the mp3 file to the range given
- avail result mp3 to user

Answer (score 0):

I found a beneficial package for cutting mp3 files: "**[pydub](http://pydub.com/)**"

get the mp3 data from your view and return it to your pydub function